# UITextView make isEditable true

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uitextview

I am trying to build a simple text editor using swiftUI and UITextView. In UITextView I am trying to use link detection which requires isEditable property to be false. But when I make isEditable false I am not able to make it true again and I am not able to type any text. No delegate method works when you make isEditable false.
Can anyone tell me how to make isEditable true again ?

UITextView, UIViewRepresentable

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    let textView = UITextView()
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent: TextView
        
        init(_ parent: TextView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            parent.text = textView.text
        }
        
        func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            textView.isEditable = false
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.dataDetectorTypes = .link
        textView.becomeFirstResponder()
        
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}
```

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = "www.apple.com"

    var body: some View {
        TextView(text: $text)
    }
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: And when (or on which condition) do you want to make it editable again?

Comment: when I tap on the open space in UITextView the keyboard should come up and I should be able to type further text. Just like the Apple’s notes app.